# The string members become empty if use *pt = &stu1

Tags: c++

sorry for the title. The code below may help to describe the problem.
I've alreay set up a `Student` class.
if doing in this way:

```
Student stu1(score, "sam",5, "aaa", "123dfkj@gmail.COM","156412", "518105" );
Student *tempSt = &stu1;
```

I try to `cout` the string members of `tempSt`, it works.
But the string members become empty when:

```
tempSt = &Student(score, "sam",6, "aaa", "123dfkj@QQ.COM","156412", "518105" );
```

What is happening?
Hope you understand my poor description :)

update:

the problem stems from this:

```
void myList::add(Student *a) {
slistNode *tempNode = new slistNode();
tempNode->data = a;

if(lastNode == NULL) {
    headNode = tempNode;
    lastNode = tempNode;
} else {
    lastNode->next = tempNode;
    lastNode = tempNode;
}

++listLength;
```

}

I try to put those objs into a list, So I want those obj to be temporary(actually I want them no name). I don't want to make a lot objs like stu1, stu2, stu3....

slistNode class:

```
class slistNode {
public:
slistNode() { 
    next = NULL;
}
Student *data;
slistNode *next;
};
```

Comment: Yup. Temporary -> destroyed -> UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a pointer to a temporary object. The object this pointer points to will be destructed before code reaches next line. As the object is destroyed of course accessing the string members invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: In what situation a temporary object won't be destructed?

Comment: There is no such situation. That is why it is **temporary**

Comment: @chbdetta: when you have a `const &` to your constructed object, like in `const Student& s = Student(...)` it will live as long as your variable is in scope.  But don't rely on such behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, this:

```
Student(score, "sam",6, "aaa", "123dfkj@QQ.COM","156412", "518105" );
```

constructs a temporary object. That's destructed right after its construction. Taking its address invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B).

(If you started with C instead of C++, the compiler wouldn't even permit you to commit suicide. Yay for brainless design decisions in C++!)

Comment: @chbdetta You stick with the first option: assign it to a variable.

Comment: If I want to build a lot of obj, wouldn't that way takes a lot memory?

Comment: @chbdetta it would. And then what?

Comment: how to prevent large memory use..? :)

Comment: @chbdetta Design your algorithms well?

Comment: @chbdetta: Lots of objects takes lots of memory. That's pretty clearly unavoidable.

Comment: @chbdetta: Pointers aren't free, they also require memory in addition to the objects they point to.